# SonarQube - Why condition Coverage metrics on catch statement

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the java code like

```
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(i);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
```

For this I have all the test written and I am using Sonarqube as code coverage tool. But unfortunately conditional coverage result(`2 conditions are covered by test`) is coming in my `catch` statement. As far my knowledge, conditional coverage is apply only for condition check. Why it is showing in `catch` statement. Can someone shed some light here.

Comment: To catch or not to catch, I'd say. Did one of your test tested what happened in case of an exception?

Comment: Yes, I had the same thought but I covered that in my test already

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This an issue on JaCoCo side due to the try-with-resource construction : 
The bytecode generated have several branches in order to safely close the open resource and JaCoCo instrument bytecode and report some of those branches as uncovered.

See this issue : https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/82 and this one https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/15 for more detailed explanation.